# Partial Integration of outer product of del and position vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics, integration

I am trying to understand the solution I have been given to prove the following relation for a current density $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$ that is concentrated around the origin:

$$
\int_V dV \, (\vec{\nabla} \otimes \vec{r})  \cdot \vec{j}(\vec{r})=0  \tag{*}
$$

where $\otimes$ is the tensor product, $\cdot$ the dot product, and $V$ covers the entire space.

The solution now uses integration by parts and seemingly the divergence theorem:

$$
(*) = \int_{\partial \infty } (d\vec{f} \otimes \vec{r}) \cdot \vec{j}(\vec{r}) - \int_V dV (\vec{r}^T \otimes \vec{\nabla}^T) \cdot \vec{j}(\vec{r}) \tag{**}
$$

How did this conversion happen?

The relations that I assume have been used are

$$(\vec{x}\otimes \vec{y})\cdot \vec{z} = \vec{x}(\vec{y}\cdot \vec{z}) \tag{1}$$

And maybe the theorem for integration by parts in multiple dimensions
$$
\int_\Omega\phi\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\,dV=\int_{\partial\Omega}\phi\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{S}-\int_{\Omega}\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\phi\,dV\tag{2}
$$

I am having difficulties understanding how partial integration and dyad product work together, especially how $d\vec{f}$ appears within the product in $(**)$.